# Cron job not abiding by the nice command

Tags: linux, bash, nice

I got a script that backs up minecraft worlds, when ran by command (nice -19 ./backup.sh) it doesn't lag what so ever, server load stays low. When I try to do nice -19 ./backup.sh  in a cronjob, it doesn't "nice" it and it uses a high amount of server resources.  Isn't there a renice command? Can't I some how input that in the code to make it renice itself everytime it runs? But how would I get the PID of the script?

Thank you!

Comment: Firstly this doesn't belong on stackoverflow.  2ndly: which user are you doing this as?  Thirdly: you're misinterpreting nice.  If it does use lots of CPUs it's most likely doing the right thing  in cron.  -19 is a "totally not nice" niceness. -20 is the highest priority, 19 is the lowest. Normal users can only do nicenesses from 0 to 19. Only root can do negative.

Comment: @tink - `nice -10 <cmd>` isn't "minus 19", it's usually interpreted as `plus 19` althoug the correct form would be [`nice -n 10 <cmd>`](http://man.he.net/?topic=nice&section=all)

Comment: ta :) for the feedback, can't edit my comment any more :/

Answer (score 0):

Inside your script you should both `renice` it and `ionice` it, e.g. in `bash`:

```
#!/bin/bash

renice 19 -p $$
ionice -c 3 -p $$

...
```

The `$$` in `bash` stands for the process ID of the current `bash`.